# How to compute Probability of winning atleast k out of N games

Tags: algorithm, probability, combinatorics

Problem is simple , that given K and N , what is the probability of winning atleast K out of N games when probability of winning or loosing a single game is equal i.e 1/2 .

Only thing is N is as large as 10^6.

using prime factorization i can efficiently compute probability of exactly K wins out of N games, but it doesn't seem efficient for at least K.

Kindly provide an efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for **CDF** (*Cumulative Distribution Function* - probability 
that distribution function will take a value less than or equal to `x`.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

In your case - [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) `CDF` is [Regularized Incomplete Beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedBetaFunction.html):

```
  CDF(p, N, K) = I(1 - p, N - K, 1 + K)
```

In your case (`p = 1/2`)

```
  P(N, K) = 1 - I(0.5, N - K + 1, K)
```

Many math engines provide such *beta functions*, e.g. Free [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) uses [betainc](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Special-Functions.html):

```
  N = 10; # 10 games
  K = 2;  # win at least 2 
  1 - betainc(0.5, N - K + 1, K)
```

Outcome

```
  0.98926
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets denote

```
P(k,n)= Probability of winning atleast k out of n games
```

Now,

```
P(k,n) = P(k,n| nth chance was win)*P(nth win) +  P(k,n| nth chance was lost)*P(nth lost)
       = 1/2*P(k-1,n-1) + 1/2*P(k,n-1)
```

If you use this recursion, you don't need to do prime factorization.